# Knockoutjs - attach observable data to created node during custom binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm writing a custom binding for Knockout.

In the custom binding I loop through an array and create nodes (*i.e.*, HTML elements) for each element (usually an observable but doesn't have to be), then I set the value and attributes of that dynamically-created node to that of context observable/object.

However, when I call `ko.dataFor` on one of these dynamically-created nodes I receive the *outer* observableArray that was specified rather than the inner observable which I'm using for that specific node.

In my head, this makes sense because I haven't actually attached a more specific observable (or object of any kind) to this dynamically-created node.

So my question is, inside a custom binding how do I attach data to a node? Or to put it another way, what's the *opposite* of `ko.dataFor`?

**Update:** I've tried using

```
ko.utils.domData.set(elmnt, "data", currentObservable);
```

And then when I call

```
ko.utils.domData.get(element, "data");
```

I get the observable back again. However, `ko.dataFor` still returns the outermost observable which was bound to the containing element, which makes me feel that I'm not using the correct methodology here.

And just to be clear, when I say "containing element" I'm referring to the only DOM element which existed when `ko.applyBindings` was called; this is the element which has the `data-bind` attribute. All the other (inner) elements are then added by the custom binding.

**Update 2**: This question was written in relation to a Knockout custom binding that I've been writing. This custom binding can be viewed [here](https://raw2.github.com/Supertext/knockout.groupedOptions/master/knockout-groupedOptions.js). Specifically, towards the end of the javascript file you can see that I've used

```
ko.utils.domData.set(option, "data", thisOption);
```

and in the "init" handler near the top of the file I've retrieved this using

```
ko.utils.domData.get(node, "data");
```

What I'd really like to know is, is this the ideal approach for 'storing' the observable data with the element for later retrieval? And why can't I use `ko.dataFor` against this method of 'storing'?

Comment: Can you extend your code to make it into a working example? It's kinda hard to imagine the view model and complete binding you're after.

Comment: (In any case, wouldn't extending the actual observable (it's just a JS object) be an option?)

Comment: I'm working on extending my own plugin that I've been using for some time, and hopefully in the next few hours I'll have it on GitHub with a couple of JSFiddle examples. Before then it's kind of awkward to give an example. As simply as I can put it: if my custom binding dynamically adds DOM nodes and a 'change' handler, when this 'change' handler is fired how can I retrieve the observable that was bound to this dynamically-created DOM element?

Comment: Have you tried using templates? You can dynamically add DOM elements, then render a template inside them with `ko.renderTemplate`